# How to batter something wet?

Tags: eggs, temperature, frying, deep-frying, batter

I'm trying to batter a frozen egg but the egg melts as I try to batter it and it falls off about half the time.

I notice when I cool the batter mixture and flour mixture before hand it has a better chance to stick without any holes.

Any ways to batter a wet objects while having an even distribution and no clumps?

My only thought for this specific scenario would be to do it in a cool temp the whole time or even freeze the batter on.

Comment: Did you try dredging in flour before dipping in batter?

Comment: Yes, that's what the flour mix I stated above was for.